# What was the life cycle of population III stars?

Tags: main-sequence, stellar-population

Is the life cycle of population III, II, and I roughly the same, save in timescale? Did III go through the same phases, or equivalents of them, for instance, was their an equivalent "main sequence" phase for population III stars, and a "giant" or "supergiant" phase?

Comment: I think the most significant parameters that influences the evolution of a star is its mass. The higher the mass, the faster it goes through its evolution stages. As far as I know, the main difference between these theee generation is their chemical composition ( since the heavy elements are generate through nuclear synthesis. Population III stars had no predecessors and therefore had had few metal) Another difference which I’m not sure is that Population III stars may had been quite massive, and therefore had evolved rapidly and gone very soon after their birth.